# Ionic 5 routing in same url page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

Hello i want to make a routing from a page to go to the same url page but with different params. I am guessing that it can not go to same url page because i use routing and it goes to other pages just fine but not to same url page. This is what i got so far

profile-routing.page.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ProfilePage } from './profile.page';

  const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfilePage
  }
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class ProfilePageRoutingModule {}
```

profile.html

```
<ion-thumbnail class="story-avatar" [ngClass]="{'seen': false}" (click)="goProfile(item)"
```

profile.ts

```
 goProfile(profile: any) {
this.userData.profileViewed(profile).pipe(
  map((data: any) => {
    if (data.success) {
      const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
        state: {
          profile: profile
        }
      };
     this.router.navigate(['app/tablinks/home/profile'], navigationExtras);
    }
  })
).subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities that might be creating the error.  Try:

1. Adding a '/' before app in the navigate line
2. Using `navigateByUrl`
3. Breaking up the path like this

   this.router.navigate(['/', 'app',  'tablinks', 'home', 'profile'], navigationExtras);

Comment: doesnt work. at least with navigate. With navigateByUrl will have to be different syntax

Comment: Both `this.DeliverRouter.navigate(['/', 'auth']);` and `this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');` are working fine in my Ionic 5/Angular 9 app